# How do I select this div in CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors

The only class that I am allowed to use is `.servicebox`
I've tried this:

```
.servicebox div > div > div:last-child{
        padding: 0;
}
```

but it is selecting more div, not the last one.

[image]

Comment: use its id , there should be no mistake since id are supposed to be used only once per document

Comment: The last-child sould be on the second div, not the third

Comment: I can't, the id's are coming from Typo3 CMS, and they can change, based on what element is added or not in the back-end by the client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `:last-child` on the second div

```
  .servicebox div > div:last-child > div{
      padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about by id: 
`#c951 { /*your css*/ }`

Answer (score 0):

I beleive

```
div.servicebox > div > div > div.csc-default
```

should work if your last div that your are interested has a unique class. If not then:

```
div.servicebox > div > div > div#c951
```

should work.