# Exclude multiple divs in CSS selector using multiple :not pseudo class

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have some html code, in which I want to apply a specific style of red color font and width of 250px to all input elements of type button or text, but only in divs with class of *div2* or *.div3*. This is shown in screen shot pasted below.

In other words, I am trying to exclude this specific style for div with class  RadWindow and also for div with id div1. The CSS I have tried as below does nothing.

**Question** : What would be the correct CSS selector to exclude the above mentioned divs from following specific styling `color: red; width :250px`?

[image: Exclude multiple divs from CSS styling]

```css
 .RadWindow, #div1, .div2, .div3 {
     margin:20px;
    }
  div:not(.RadWindow):not(#div1)   input[type='button'],div:not(.RadWindow):not(#div1)  input[type='text']  {
        width: 250px;
        color: red;
    }
    div:not(.RadWindow):not(#div1) {
     font-weight:bold;
    }
```

```html
<div class="RadWindow">
<div>
   <div>
   RadWindow div (should not be red color)
   </div>
   <div>
      <input type="button" value="Button 1 in RadWindow" />
   </div>
   <div>
     <input type="text" value="textbox 1 in RadWindow" />
   </div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="div1"> 
<div>
 <div>
   div1 div (should not be red color)
   </div>
 <div>
      <input type="button" value="Button 1 in div1" />
   </div>
   <div>
     <input type="text" value="TextBox 1 in div1" />
   </div>
   </div>
</div>
 <div class="div2">
  <div>
   div2 div (should be red color)
   </div>
   <div>
      <input type="button" value="Button 1 in div2" />
   </div>
   <div>
     <input type="text" value="Textbox 1 in div2" />
   </div>
</div>   
<div class="div3">
  <div>
   div3 div (should be red color)
   </div>
   <div>
      <input type="button" value="Button 1 in div3" />
   </div>
   <div>
     <input type="text" value="Textbox 1 in div3" />
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have heard that the `:not` element is not well supported.

Comment: In CSS3, it is well-supported I think, or not?

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid: That was true 10 years ago.

Comment: Between your markup and [this guy's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42181428/how-do-i-select-this-div-in-css) I'm not sure whose is suffering from a more severe case of divitis.

Comment: @Sunil In your code hierarchy of divs are different For first 2 divs(RadWindow,div1) and last 2 divs(div2,div3). Will you please tell this is by mistake or you have this same

Comment: @B.Desai, That is how it is.

Comment: @BoltClock http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-not-sel-list

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid: That's the level 4 :not(). We're talking about the level 3 :not(). Level 3 :not() has been supported by every browser since at least 2011. That's nearly 6 years now.

Comment: My initial remark about poor support of `:not()` selector was based on a confusion which appears to be common, between CSS3 [`:not(single selector)`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3), which is widely supported and the CSS4 [`:not(selector list)`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-not-sel-list). I guess the confusion is common because if you type `:not()` in the search box of `caniuse`, the CSS4 one shows up first. I realized it now and came here to apologize and clarify. However, I still think `:not()` should be avoided based on poor performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this result you want?

```css
.RadWindow,
#div1,
.div2,
.div3 {
  margin: 20px;
}

:not(.RadWindow):not(#div1)>div>div>input[type='button'],
:not(.RadWindow):not(#div1)>div>div>input[type='text'] {
  width: 250px !important;
  color: red !important;
}

div:not(.RadWindow):not(#div1) {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="RadWindow">
  <div>
    <div>
      RadWindow div (should not be red color)
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="button" value="Button 1 in RadWindow" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" value="textbox 1 in RadWindow" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="div1">
  <div>
    <div>
      div1 div (should not be red color)
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="button" value="Button 1 in div1" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" value="TextBox 1 in div1" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="div2">
  <div>
    div2 div (should be red color)
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="button" value="Button 1 in div2" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" value="Textbox 1 in div2" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="div3">
  <div>
    div3 div (should be red color)
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="button" value="Button 1 in div3" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" value="Textbox 1 in div3" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a version of it that does not use `:not()`.

```css
.RadWindow, #div1, .div2, .div3 {
  margin:20px;
}

input[type='button'],
input[type='text'] {
  width: 250px;
  color: red;
}
.RadWindow input[type='button'],
.RadWindow input[type='text'],
div#div1 input[type='button'],
div#div1 input[type='text'] {
  color: initial;
}
div[id^="div"] {
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="RadWindow">
  <div>
    <div>
      RadWindow div (should not be red color)
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="button" value="Button 1 in RadWindow" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" value="textbox 1 in RadWindow" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="div1"> 
  <div>
    <div>
      div1 div (should not be red color)
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="button" value="Button 1 in div1" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" value="TextBox 1 in div1" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="div2">
  <div>
    div2 div (should be red color)
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="button" value="Button 1 in div2" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" value="Textbox 1 in div2" />
  </div>
</div>   
<div class="div3">
  <div>
    div3 div (should be red color)
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="button" value="Button 1 in div3" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" value="Textbox 1 in div3" />
  </div>
</div>
```